# Unmarshal json into struct: cannot unmarshal array into Go value

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have a service which provides me properties through REST. Now I want to unmarshal the body into a properties struct. Please see this playground example: [click](http://play.golang.org/p/m7RV9pGadj). When I have only one property, I can easily unmarshal it into a `Property`. However the ACTUAL response from the server is somehow difference. The actual response I want to unmarshal is this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "blabla",
        "secret": false,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "hereisthevalue"
    },
    {
        "key": "yepyepakey",
        "secret": true,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "dummy"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to unmarshal this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to unmarshal into a slice of Property:
http://play.golang.org/p/eRgjfBHypH

```
var props []Property
er := json.Unmarshal(resp, &props)
if er != nil {
    panic(er)
} else {
    fmt.Println(props)
}
```